# Common binaries with support for command execution, like `awk` and `vim`, not respecting setuid bit?

Tags: setuid, suid

I'm hardening a Linux system and wanted to test (`setuid`-based) shell escapes using common binaries, like `awk`, `vim`, etc., supporting command executing.

However, all binaries I've tested except `sh` and `bash` don't respect their `setuid` bit.

In particular, `awk` continues to execute as a normal user:

```
$ ls -lL /usr/bin/awk
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 121976 Mar 23  2012 /usr/bin/awk
$ id
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) groups=1000(bob)
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("id")}'
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) groups=1000(bob)
```

In contrast, `bash` executes as `root` when given the `-p` option:

```
$ ls -la /bin/bash
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 1168776 Apr 18  2019 /bin/bash
$ /bin/bash -p
# id
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) euid=0(root) groups=1000(bob)
```

Is there any way to make `awk`, `vim`, `less`, etc. respect the `setuid` bit and execute the command as `root`?

**OS**:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

**Update**:

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ ls -la /proc/self/fd/0 /dev/fd/0 /dev/stdin
lrwx------ 1 parallels parallels 64 Mar 26 08:15 /dev/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root      root      15 Mar 20 19:56 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 parallels parallels 64 Mar 26 08:15 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/1
```

Comment: @StephenKitt - will you elaborate? I only know of real uid and effective uid. Furthermore, how can I check the ruid? And how can I turn my command into e.g. a `bash` root shell?

Comment: `awk` works as intended. Try this, `awk 1 /etc/shadow` and if it honours its setuid bit it will display the contents of the otherwise protected shadow file.

Comment: id shows you the effective UID, "id -r" the real one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ ls -lL /usr/bin/awk
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 121976 Mar 23  2012 /usr/bin/awk
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("id")}'
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) groups=1000(bob)
```

In your example, it's not `awk` which is dropping privileges or not "respecting its setuid bit", but the `/bin/sh` command that awk uses to implement its `system()` function.

Just like its C counterpart, awk's `system()` does not parse and run the command directly, but by passing it as an argument to `/bin/sh -c`. If `/bin/sh` is bash (or the Debian version of dash, or a couple of other shells which copied this misfeature from bash), it will reset its effective uid back to the real one.

The same thing applies to `print | "cmd"` or `"cmd" | getline` in awk -- they're implemented with `popen(3)` which calls `/bin/sh -c`. Notice that it's always `/bin/sh` (or the system's shell, eg. `/system/bin/sh` on Android), not the user's login shell or that from the `$SHELL` environment variable. **[1]**

This is different in perl: perl's `system`, `exec`, `open "|-"`, `open2`, `open3`, etc will run the command directly if they're called with multiple arguments or if the command does not contain shell metacharacters:

```
$ id -nu
ahq
$ ls -l /tmp/perl
-rwsr-xr-x 1 dummy_user dummy_user 3197768 Mar 24 18:13 /tmp/perl
$ env - /tmp/perl -e 'system("id -nu")'
dummy_user
$ env - /tmp/perl -e 'system("{ id -nu; }")'
ahq
```

This example is on Debian 10. On other systems like FreeBSD or older Debian, both commands will print the same thing, because their `/bin/sh` does not drop privileges. **[2]**

---

**Notes:**

**[1]** Other programs like `vim` and `less` do use the `$SHELL` environment variable, so they're easily "fixable" by pointing it to some wrapper. In `vim` you could also use `:set shcf=-pc` to pass the `-p` option to the shell used for the `:!` and similar commands.

**[2]** The perl example will also work on OpenBSD just like on FreeBSD, provided that you replace the `env - /tmp/perl 'script'` with the more obtuse `echo 'script' | /tmp/perl /dev/fd/0`.

OpenBSD's perl will reject the `-e` argument and refuse to read its script from the stdin when running in setuid mode (see [this](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/f12bbb761071acfd5663d673ad891ffbb2ffdbd9/perl.c#L4059) which is ending [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/f12bbb761071acfd5663d673ad891ffbb2ffdbd9/perl.c#L4275) -- OpenBSD supposedly has secure setuid scripts).

But that does not apply to `/dev/fd/N`, which perl is [handling itself](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/f12bbb761071acfd5663d673ad891ffbb2ffdbd9/perl.c#L4017) when given as a script name (only the `/dev/fd/N` form, not `/dev/stdin` or `/proc/self/fd/N`).

```
obsd66$ ls -l /tmp/perl
-rwsr-xr-x  1 dummy_user  dummy_user  10728 Mar 25 18:34 /tmp/perl

obsd66$ env - /tmp/perl -e 'system("{ id -nu; }")'
No -e allowed while running setuid.

obsd66$ echo 'system("{ id -nu; }")' | env - /tmp/perl
No program input from stdin allowed while running setuid.

obsd66$ echo 'system("{ id -nu; }")' | env - /tmp/perl /dev/stdin
Can't open perl script "/dev/stdin": Operation not permitted

obsd66$ echo 'system("{ id -nu; }")' | env - /tmp/perl /dev/fd/0
dummy_user
```

```
debian10$ su - other_user -c 'perl /dev/fd/7' 7<<<'print "OK\n"'
OK
debian10$ su - other_user -c 'perl /proc/self/fd/7' 7<<<'print "OK\n"'
Can't open perl script "/proc/self/fd/7": Permission denied
```

Comment: So, the only way to have e.g. `awk` execute commands as `root` is to replace the system's shell with another one that doesn't reset the euid? I guess, that's good for security, but not from a developer's point of perspective.

Comment: Are you using `/dev/fd/0` as an argument to `perl`, since the piped input is available on that file descriptor?

Comment: Because OpenBSD's perl will not accept an -e script or reading the script from stdin when running in setuid mode. See the [edit history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/574654/edit); the prev version used the less obtuse `env - /tmp/perl -e 'system("...")'`. I haven't investigated yet if this is a feature in new versions of perl, or it's an OpenBSD addition. `env - /tmp/perl <(echo 'system("id -nu")')` would work too, and not mess with perl's stdin, but not all shells support `<(...)` process substitution.

Comment: But isn't `/dev/fd/0` stdin, which you say `perl` cannot read from setuid mode?

Comment: No, `open("/dev/fd/0", ...)` will ALWAYS return a fd != 0, ie a fd other than stdin. The `/dev/fd/` mechanism works differently in Linux vs BSD/Solaris/etc, but that one thing is 100% sure ;-) As to that "no script from stdin when setuid" in perl being kind of dumb, it's not me who invented it.

Comment: On my Debian 10, `env - /usr/bin/perl -e 'system("cat /etc/shadow")'` works just fine - I don't need the `/dev/fd/0`.

Comment: Please see my update. All `/dev/fd/0`, `/dev/stdin`, and `/proc/self/fd/0` refer to the same character device `/dev/pts/1`. When calling `open("...")` on any of these, one get a `fd != 0` that is effectively `stdin`, thus not having the same integer value (0)? Are we talking about a cloned version of `stdin`?

Comment: No, you get a "cloned" version of stdin (the same you would get with `dup(2)`) _on *BSD and Solaris_. On Linux, the file would be opened _from scratch_, going through the directory entry and considering the inode's permissions. My point from the extra note and the very last example is that perl is handling itself specially a path like `/dev/fd/N` when given as a script name: perl will NOT open the path, but use the fd directly, perversely bypassing the expected behaviour on Linux (and OpenBSD, where the `/dev/fd/N` cannot be opened from a setuid program).

Comment: __tl;dr__ you can ignore everything from the Note: below in the context of this answer. That's a bug I hit upon when trying to create a portable example which demonstrate how system(), etc work in perl. They're not affected by that.

Comment: How do you use a fd directly (`/dev/fd/N`) from a program without opening the file first?

Comment: What kind of program? The perl interpreter is written in C, so it just uses the fd (a short int) directly in functions like `read(2)`, `write(2)`. If you look at the [link](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/f12bbb761071acfd5663d673ad891ffbb2ffdbd9/perl.c#L4017) from the note, you'll see that it passes it to `fdopen()` (actually, perl's internal (PerlIO) `fdopen()`, but that doesn't matter).

Comment: I tested `sudo /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{system("/bin/bash")}'`, which runs as root on Debian 10. Why doesn't `/bin/sh` drop privileges here? Is it because `sudo` makes both uid and euid to root, before running `awk`, whereas the setuid approach only sets euid to root?

Comment: e‎x‎a‎c‎t‎l‎y
‎